# In DynamoDB single-table design, should the shard lookup be in a separate table?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I'm trying to design a multi-tenant single-table in Dynamodb. My primary key needs to be the `tenantId` for all items so that I can enforce tenant isolation. The PK potentially faces hotkey issues due to this design. I have a tenant entity type in the table. Should I keep the sharding lookup values as an attribute of the tenant item or should I create a separate lookup table?

My thinking is that since the shard gathering query would have to be performed separately I won't be benefiting from the single-table design so much and instead looking into the future I can potentially speedup the shard lookups by using DAX.

Does this make sense or am I missing something?

*Edit: Added context as to why I'm looking into sharding.*

Comment: You're definitely missing something. What is your table design, and why do you need to shard the tenantId?

Comment: I need to set the PK to be the tenantId for all items so that I can isolate tenants with fine grained access control by using dynamodb:LeadingKeys in my IAM policy and setting it to the tenantId. But this can potentially create hot key issues, right?

Comment: How many writes and reads per second do you need per tenant?

Comment: I'm aware of the 1000 write and 3000 reads per second limit for each partition key for on-demand ddbs and to be honest this is a new app so we're not sure what the demand would be, it may never hit those limits. We're not going to implement sharding until we need it and we'll have CloudWatch alarms set to monitor for us getting close to those limits. But I was planning ahead and wanted to know what would be the best approach if in fact we do end up needing to do sharding. Thanks

Comment: If you do need to shard, you don't need a lookup key. Imagine you have a tenant that needs 2500 WCU. Then you would give them 3 shards. `TenantId#1`, `TenantId#2`, `TenantId#3`. You randomly write items to each one.

Comment: Another option is to hash a portion of the item that you will know at read time along with the TenantId.